# Python3: Error with colon in if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error

I have just been learning python, and seems like my first issue poped-up.
It is giving syntax error for my colon(:) usage in if statements. I don't know exactly, I feel like I did everything right.

```
packagea = 300
packageb = 600
name = input("Please enter your name: ")
ti = int(input("Which package u used last month? A, B or C?:"))
hours = float(input(" how many hours did you use?:")
if ti>0:
    a=packagea-hours*60
    if a < 0:
        a=a*(-1)*0.08
        ab=9.95+a
        print("you used", ab)
    else
        print("you have used less than limit, so your total cost is 9.95USD")
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce...

Comment: your colon usage is fine. Something else is the problem.

Comment: You probably have weird indentation in your original code or something.

Comment: Add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: [it is interpreted just fine](https://repl.it/repls/PleasingIdenticalWildebeest)

Comment: @ArneRecknagel Python is not a compiled language.

Comment: try to post a full example with initialization of `ti`, `packA`, etc.

Comment: Usually with syntax errors like this it's the line above that is causing the problem

Comment: just updated the code

Comment: You forgot the colon for the else statement - `else:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put one ")" the line before the if and also the last "else" is missing a ":"

Answer (score 0):

In the line
ti = int(input("Which package u used last month? A, B or C?:"))

You ask the user to enter a number(integer) but give them the choice of a,b,c. It will give you an error.

hours = float(input(" how many hours did you use?:")

You have a missing ")"

you forgot your colon  ":" after your else .